# Egit: My files are updated in all the branches

Tags: repository, egit

I am using EGit in Eclipse. I have one local repository with a Working directory and two branches. I have create a branch based on the master branch. I have added a folder and a file in the folder in the "secondary" branch. When i switch to the master branch, the folder i have created in the other branch and the files are showing up in the master branch and in the working directory.

Did i miss something? According to me it shouldnt show up and only when i push the secondary branch to the master one.

Could you please help on that

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating something in the filesystem (for example with `mkdir` or `touch`) doesn't mean anything in Git. Once you commit the changeset, a new Commit object is created, and `HEAD` points to that commit on the current branch (possibly different from the default one, `master`). As long as you don't commit anything, your filesystem objects (file and directories) are not tracked by Git; instead, they effectively float around, so when you `git checkout SOMETHING` you end up with the new (untracked) objects or maybe an error message.

Comment: Ok, when i switch branch i see in my eclipse project explorer that it has correctly switched branch but whatever i do my eclipse explorer will directly work to what is consider the "working directory" in the local repository. Is it normal that i work directly in this directory? Lets say i have clone a repo and decide to create a secondary branch. What shall i do then to  have those change saved (new folder, new files) in this secondary branch but not that it doesnt appear when i switch back to master branch.

Comment: Switch to the secondary branch, do your work, then commit as normal (right click on the file/directory). This way your edits are saved in the experimental branch, and when you checkout another revision they disappear